# Missing UIView in Array

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, uiview

I am adding UIViews in an array. On a button click, I am adding them to another view. Works perfectly.

The problem is, when I add a view more than one time in the array. The view sets only one time.

Here is my code.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender {

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UIView *view4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
    [view4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view2, view2, view1, view4, view3, nil];

    [self setViews:views];

}

-(void) setViews:(NSArray*)views {

    [testView1 addSubview: [views objectAtIndex:0]];
    [testView2 addSubview: [views objectAtIndex:1]];
    [testView3 addSubview: [views objectAtIndex:2]];
    [testView4 addSubview: [views objectAtIndex:3]];
    [testView5 addSubview: [views objectAtIndex:4]];
}
```

The output is, [image]

For `NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view4, view4, view3, nil];`, the output is, [image]

For `NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, view4, nil];`, the output is, [image]

I am making it more clear. For `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view1, view1, view1, view1, nil];`, testView1,2,3,4 is empty and `view1` is added to `testView5`.

How can bring the perfect output, no matter how many times a view is added?

I'd like to hear to your explanations..!

Comment: I think there is a problem in uploading the pictures.

Comment: The position of the repeated view will be empty in the output.

Comment: where you place the views(testView1,2,3,4)? are you created programmatically? can you post that code also?

Comment: @karthika.. I added them in xib. Also mapped.

Comment: try changing the origin of the same view when u add it again on the testViews

Comment: I guess there is no issue in that part.

Comment: I am making it more clear. For [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view1, view1, view1, view1, nil];, testView1,2,3,4 is empty and view1 is added to testView5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a)

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

That means, calling `addSubview` multiple times for adding same subview will only add it once on the superview (since the receiver will be same).

**Solution**: You will have to make multiple copies of the view you want to repeat as a subview.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For loop over `subviews` array of your superview? I doubt it will give you repeated count. Instead check at the point in your code where you decide you want to repeat a subview and then create a copy.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that if you insert twice an object into an array, as it is the same object, it will paint (when you call `addSubview` method) the latest reference of it. It is not a copy, it is the same object.

So, if you do this:

```
UIView *a,*b,*c,*d;

NSArray *array = @[a,a,b,c,d];
```

And you give a different place view to them, you will see painted the latest referenced A view. Your `setViews` method will paint 'a' in the first location and when you access again to the same view it will remove it from first location and draw it in the second one.

So, if you want to solve it, create copies of them before paint it again. Create new instances of your views.

Hope it help!

Answer (score 2):

you can add a view only once in the subview hierarchy by `addSubView` method. 
And you are doing that. So the repeating view is adding only once.

Comment: So what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize another object with same frame for the repeating views. Like:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

UIView *view21 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[view21 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

UIView *view3 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[view3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

UIView *view4 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[view4 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view2, view21, view1, view4, view3, nil];

[self setViews:views];
```

Answer (score 0):

The views you add more then once, appear on the same frame because you are not changing the frame when adding them as sub view. So repeated views share the same position and hence overlap each other. You will need to change frame of the repeated view programmatically before adding them as subview

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution..! Taking duplicate.

```
UIView *subview;
NSData *tempArchive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[views objectAtIndex:0]];
subview = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:tempArchive];
[testView1 addSubview: subview];
```

doing so for each view gives me the solution..!